# Wait to perform two actions - selenium/ java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ui-automation, fluentwait

I'm trying to use Fluent wait to perform two actions as below:

1. Click on search button
2. Check the result for the element

Right now I'm trying with the below code and it doesn't seem to work:

```
 public SendMailPage waitForSometime() throws Exception {

    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {

        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@type='submit'][text()='Search']")).click();

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the element i'm waiting to find"));

            return driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the element i'm waiting to find"));
        }

    });

    element.isDisplayed();

    return new SendMailPage();
}
```

Can someone guide me on how to fix this?

***UPDATED CODE: where waiting for a single element also doesn't work :

```
public SendMailPage assertMailSubject() throws Exception {
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {

          public  WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {


         return driver.findElement(By.xpath("the element that i am waiting for"));
                                        }
                                    }
    );
    return new SendMailPage();
}
```

Comment: Separate each one of them into separate `wait.until` calls.

Comment: For some reason, even with one `wait.until` the code doesn't wait.

Comment: Please post the updated code.

Comment: I have updated the OP now.

Comment: I am sure that your wait is succeeding. Can you add a sop for element and check? May be you are waiting for a wrong element.

Comment: I gave an element that is not even in the page. But it fails immediately without even waiting and checking. Because I get the error as soon as the code runs.

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: Element not found. The thing is it throws up immediately rather than throwing it after 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed both the problems:

1. The code was not working as the `NoSuchElementException` was from Java util instead of Selenium.
2. And for performing two actions, I just added by Search key action before the return statement.